# How to combine multiple arrayFilters for a single key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

Let's say I have a schema in this format:

```
const some_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "id": { type: Number },
    "list": [
        {
            id: { type: Number },
            value: { type: Number }
        }
    ]
})
```

I need to update multiple objects in the `list` using `arrayFilters` given that every key in the `arrayFilters` is unique and will only match 1 object in the `list`.

I can make dynamic keys using JS like so:

```
//original doc values:
{
    "id": 10,
    "list": [
        { id: 1, value: 5 },
        { id: 2, value: 10 }
     ]
}

let updates = [ { id: 1, newValue: 10 }, { id: 2, newValue: 20 }];
let queryOptions = { arrayFilters: [] }, queryUpdates = { $set: {} };

for (const key in updates) {
    queryOptions.arrayFilters.push({ [`${key}`]: key });
    queryUpdates.$set[[`elem.$[${key}].value`]] = updates[key].newValue;
}
//update query
await doc.updateOne(queryUpdates, queryOptions);

//updated doc values:
{
    "id": 10,
    "list": [
        { id: 1, value: 10 },
        { id: 2, value: 20 }
     ]
}
```

Is there some way to do this directly in `arrayFilters` or some other method in MongoDB without having to make dynamic keys like the above?

Comment: whats wrong with this approach btw

Comment: I get a little lost in the dynamic building there.  Are you trying to do this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/JyFNd0NlP0L

Answer (score 1):

You may work on the update with the aggregation pipeline.

1. `$let` - Declare the variable(s) with `updates` array.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate each element in the `list` array.

   1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge the current iterated element (`ori`) with the result from *1.1.1.1*. If the result does exist, the current iterated element's fields will be updated. Otherwise, it remains as the original.

   1.1.1.1. `$first` & `$filter` - Get the first matching element from the `newList` by matching `id`.

```
await doc.updateOne({
  id: 10 // Update condition
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      list: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            newList: updates
          },
          in: {
            $map: {
              input: "$list",
              as: "ori",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$ori",
                  {
                    $first: {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$$newList",
                        cond: {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$this.id",
                            "$$ori.id"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Note that the objects in the `updates` array are required to have the same field name as in your document in order to update (overwrite) the value.

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VgMuVnxlgTP)